# Symfony 5 form builder: Entity type/Choice type with several entities

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building sort of an accounting web app and I have, among others, an entity for credit cards and an entity for bank accounts. The app is intended to document my expenses, so the plan is to enter all my movements and link them to the account/credit card they were paid by; thus, the `Movement` entity has a `ManyToOne` relationship to the `Account` and/or the `CreditCard` entity.

The `EntityType` would allow me to select the appropriate account and credit card by writing:

```php
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($movement)
    ->add('Account', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => Account::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->where('u.user = :user_id')
                ->setParameter(':user_id', $this->getUser());
        },
        'label' => 'Account name',
        'required' => true
    ))
    ->add('Credit_Card', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => CreditCard::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->where('u.user = :user_id')
                ->setParameter(':user_id', $this->getUser());
        },
        'label' => 'Credit card',
        'required' => true
    ))
    ->add('Save', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
```

This would give me two select form fields in the HTML. This is, of course, not ideal as a movement is not linked to both, an account and a credit card but only to one of both. Thus the `required` property should in fact be a `requiredIfTheOtherFieldIsEmpty` property. Ideally, I would have a segmented select field, that first displays the group of accounts and then the group of credit cards, thus something as the pseudo-code below:

```php
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($movement)
    ->add(array('Account', 'Credit_Card'), array(EntityType::class, CreditCard::class), array(
        'Account' => array(
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.user = :user_id')
                    ->setParameter(':user_id', $this->getUser());
            },
            'label' => 'Account name',
        ),
        'Credit_Card' => array(
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.user = :user_id')
                    ->setParameter(':user_id', $this->getUser());
            }
        ),
        'required' => true
    ))
    ->add('Save', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
```

Unfortunately, I [cannot find a form type](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/reference/forms/types.html) that matches these requirements. What is the correct way to handle this?

I guess that the [`ChoiceType`](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/reference/forms/types/choice.html) is a good starting point as it allows grouping, but I have no idea how I should retrieve the accounts and credit cards.

Any help is highly appreciated. If more information is needed, please ask, I'll be happy to provide as much as you need.

Comment: What about two selects where one with `Account` will update (via ajax) the other one with `Credit_Card`, maybe by preselecting/prefilling something?
Anyway, I think, you will have to create a `FormType` (e.g. `MovementType`) for your whole form. Creating something like this, with form-events inside a controller-action will be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that the ChoiceType is a good starting point as it allows grouping, but I have no idea how I should retrieve the accounts and credit cards.

Well, `EntityType` "inherits" from `ChoiceType` so almost everything you could do with `ChoiceType` you can also do with entity-type. e.g. [grouping](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by)

> This would give me two select form fields in the HTML. This is, of course, not ideal as a movement is not linked to both, an account and a credit card but only to one of both.

The quickes solutions would be to use [FormEvents](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) especially `POST_SUBMIT`. You can "manually" validate/check your input. Since you're creating your form inside  a cotronller-action with `createFormBuilder()` this is how it would look like:

First, make both selects "optional", then use `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT`

```php
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($movement)
    ->add('Account', EntityType::class, array(
       // your other options...
       'required' => false
    ))
    ->add('Credit_Card', EntityType::class, array((
       // your other options...
       'required' => false
    ))
    ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $postSubmitFormEvent) {
        /** @var App\Entity\Movement $movement */
        $movement = $postSubmitFormEvent->getData(); //
        $form = $postSubmitFormEvent->getForm();
        // don't do anything if form-data (movement) isn't valid at this point.
        // in other words: if basic validation has failed - no need to run custom
        if ($form->isValid() === false) {
            return; 
        }

        // custom validation...

        // check #1 - if both selects are empty
        if ($movement->getAccount() === null && $movement->getCreditCard() === null) {
            // create an validation-error.
            $form->addError(new FormError('Please choose at least one. Either account or credit-card.'));
        }

        // check #2 - if both select are fille/submitted
        if ($movement->getAccount() !== null && $movement->getCreditCard() !== null) {
            // create an validation-error.
            $form->addError(new FormError('You can\'t select both! Either account or credit-card.'));
        }

    })
    // your other fields....
    ->add('Save', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
```

P.S. I do recommend you to create a [form class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes) for this case.